# Udev rules' not working with 'ATTR'

Tags: linux, cpu, systemd, udev

I want to change my cpu's hwp_dynamic_boost option in /sys.  I added `ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="cpu", ATTR{intel_pstate/hwp_dynamic_boost}="1"` to /etc/udev/rules.d/99-Performance.rules. It won't work.  However, when I change the rule to `ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="cpu", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 >/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/hwp_dynamic_boost'"`, It worked!

**Question**:
Q1: Why 'ATTR' not working with cpu?
Q2: What's the difference between ATTR and RUN?